# UIScrollView doesn't scroll offset content

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, xcode4.5

I have an UIScrollView with this parameters:

```
[scrollView setPagingEnabled:YES];
[scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1024 * 2, 768)];
[scrollView setShowsHorizontalScrollIndicator:NO];
[scrollView setShowsVerticalScrollIndicator:NO];
[scrollView setScrollEnabled:NO];
[scrollView setDelegate:self];
```

For changing page:

```
CGRect frame = scrollViewPages.frame;
frame.origin.x = 1024;
[scrollViewPages scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
```

So this scrollview has a double area for display content. In the first rectangle the touch works, but when I change to the other segment, which has others components with different sizes, touch events don't work. I've read that UIScrollView doesn't apply touch events to hidden sections. I would like to know how update the view for getting touch interactions.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I was adding the UIViews into another UIVIew inside UIScrollView. Now it works